# Java - How to optimize this file writer component in a Reader/Processor/Writer pattern

Tags: java, parallel-processing, queue, etl, blocking

I have a class that is the processor component of a reader/processor/writer ETL.

It gets work streamed to it, one wrapper at a time, and it is supposed to write to file. However, I think there is a bottleneck writing to the file, as I can see the filesize going up slowly 3kb at a time, whereas I know the process class gets called much more frequently than that. Can I implement some sort of blocking queue here to wait for more wrappers to arrive before writing them to file?

```
public class RiskToFsProcessor extends Processor<> {
/**
 * Default implementation
 */
@Override
protected List<Object> process(Object wrapper) {
    FileUtils.writeLinesToFile(wrapper);
    return null;
}
```

writeLinesToFile (appends to file everytime without creating new file):

```
public static void writeLinesToFile(String fileName, String[] lines) {
    try {
        // create dir if not exist
        File file = new File(fileName);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true)));
        for (String line : lines) {
            writer.println(line.trim());
        }
        writer.close();
        LOG.debug("Write to {} finished.", fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you watching the file slowly grow?  What does `FileUtils` do?  Does a profiler indicate it's a bottleneck?

Comment: @AndrewS updated OP with writeFileToLines method. I am watching the file size on disk creep up slowly. Are there any tools I can run to confirm where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Yes - [this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) is a good place to start.